# Getting Selectbox Option Value isn't working

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am trying to get the option value from a selectbox but is isn't working:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="post" name="module_gen">
    <select id="module_gen_select_ver" name="module_gen_select_ver">
        <option value="joomla15">Joomla 1.5</option>
        <option value="joomla25_30">Joomla 2.5/3.0</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['module_gen_select_ver'] ) == 'joomla15') {
    $xmldata = '</install>';
}
elseif(isset($_POST['module_gen_select_ver'] ) == 'joomla25_30') {
    $xmldata = '</extension>';
}
```

Wne I click the submit button, it doesn't seem to be taking the value of the option into account.

Can anyone show me as to where I have gone wrong?

Comment: If you var_dump the $_POST, what do you see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your if conditions are wrong.

```
if(isset($_POST['module_gen_select_ver'] ) == 'joomla15')
```

is getting the return value of `isset($_POST['module_gen_select_ver'] )`, which is a boolean, then comparing it to `'joomla15'`, so the condition is not met. It should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['module_gen_select_ver']) and $_POST['module_gen_select_ver'] == 'joomla15')
```

The condition is still safe, as if it isn't set, the second condition won't even be read for all intents and purposes.

Or you could simply wrap both the if and elseif in `if(isset($_POST['module_gen_select_ver'])` then removing it from the if and the elseif, Thusly:

```
if(isset($_POST['module_gen_select_ver'])
{
    if($_POST['module_gen_select_ver'] == 'joomla15')
//etc
```

Comment: Ahh...right you are. thank you for the help. silly of me to forget the "and" bit. +1

Answer (score 3):

Your if logic is flawed, due to a bracketing error.  Right now, you are comparing `isset($_POST['module_gen_select_ver'] )` to `'joomla15'`.  I believe you intend to compare `$_POST['module_gen_select_ver']` to `'joomla15'`.